# Quill adds a unwanted <br> after h1

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I am using Quill as my editor on my website. I am loading new content in to Quill like this.

```
quill.setText('');

quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(0, '<h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>');
```

Now this code results in this html

```
<h1>Hello Wolrd</h1>
<p><br /></p>
```

I have matchVisual disabled in my Quill config

This is my Quill Config:

```
                let quill = new Quill(selector, {
                    placeholder: "",
                    modules: {
                        toolbar: false,
                        clipboard: {
                            matchVisual: false
                        }
                    },
                    formats: this.formatsQuill
                });
```

I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try two different approaches. First would be:

```
h1
{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Or the second could be:

```
h1 {
 display:inline;
}
```

h1's are a block-level item. You could use inline styling and a span tag to achieve this, or just class out your h1 and apply the styles there. The second is much easier to manage in the long run.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried both options. the first is not working and the second results in the following html <p><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Hello world</span></p> Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you build out a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: I will try because it is inside a very big vue application

Comment: I fixed it thank you for your help i removed the 0 from the dangerouslyPasteHTML function really weird but it works

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it was sorted. Cheers,